# disable checkbox for a short while

Tags: jquery

When users check or uncheck a checkbox, I make an ajax call, saving the setting change. On success, I display a small label notifying user that setting has been applied and then fade it out. I'd like to disable the checkbox from the time it was clicked to the time I fade out the message. How would I do this?

```
$('.role-checkbox').click(function () {
                var this_control = $(this);
                $.ajax({
                    url: _SITEURL + 'User/EnableDisableRole',
                    data: JSON.stringify({ data }),
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function () {
                        var saved_label = $('<span class="label label-success">Saved</span>')
                            .hide().appendTo(this_control.parent()).fadeIn(500).delay(3000).fadeOut(500);

                    },
                    error: function () {
                        var saved_label = $('<span class="label label-important">Error Saving!</span>')
                            .hide().appendTo(this_control.parent()).fadeIn(500).delay(3000).fadeOut(500);
                    }
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to disable the checkbox:

```
$(this).prop('disabled',true);
```

Next, you need to undisable it in the `fadeout` callback:

```
var saved_label = $('<span class="label label-success">Saved</span>')
                  .hide()
                  .appendTo(this_control.parent())
                  .fadeIn(500)
                  .delay(3000)
                  .fadeOut(500, function(){
                      this_control.prop('disabled',false);
                  });
```

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/ezENq/

Answer (score 0):

You just need to disabled the checkbox when they click it and then removed the disable after it was clicked.

```
$('.role-checkbox').click(function () {
                var this_control = $(this);
                this_control.prop("disabled","disabled");
                $.ajax({
                    url: _SITEURL + 'User/EnableDisableRole',
                    data: JSON.stringify({ data }),
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function () {
                        this_control.removeProp("disabled");
                        var saved_label = $('<span class="label label-success">Saved</span>')
                            .hide().appendTo(this_control.parent()).fadeIn(500).delay(3000).fadeOut(500);

                    },
                    error: function () {
                        this_control.removeProp("disabled");
                        var saved_label = $('<span class="label label-important">Error Saving!</span>')
                            .hide().appendTo(this_control.parent()).fadeIn(500).delay(3000).fadeOut(500);
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: It is recommended that you use prop() for enabling / disabling elements.

Comment: You are very right. I'll change it. Still used to the old way.

Comment: `$(this)` wraps the window in the `success` and `error` callbacks.